# How do I get all the classes of an element?

Tags: c#, selenium

Please see the code below:

```
var children3 = child2.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
foreach (var child3 in children3)
{
var test = child3.GetAttribute("class");
}
```

test is populated if the element contains one class, however if it is an empty string if the element contains multiple classes.  How do I get all the classes of an element?

Comment: You could print the value returned from `child3.GetAttribute("innerHTML");` to verify the element is the one you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Even in case of multiple classes:

```
var test = child3.GetAttribute("class");
```

Will retrieve the value of *class* attribute which may consist of multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = child3.GetAttribute("class");
```

the test variable contains classes with format "class1 class2 class3", so if you want to get all call in for example array string you can split test variable with space. finally,  you will get array with 3 classes is class1, class2, class3.